# Razor and function call outputting

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

The scenario is I would like to write a hidden field with a guid value generated by the server.

Why does

`<input type="hidden" id="sampleGuid" value="@{Guid.NewGuid().ToString()};" />`

yield 'value=""' while

```
@{
     string token = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    <input type="hidden" id="sampleGuid" value="@token" />
     }
```

properly fill in 'value' with a guid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need parentheses instead of braces.

`@{ ... }` will execute ordinary **statements**, but won't print anything.

`@(...)` will print the value of an **expression**.  (and will HTML-encode it)

Answer (score 1):

You've wrapped `Guid.NewGuid().ToString()` in curly braces.

That just means you want to execute the code, not ouput it.

If you're trying to output a value, wrap the code in parenthesis.